# Creating Email Alerts based on thresholds in bash

Tags: perl, bash, shell, sed, threshold

I would like to setup an alert that activates and sends an email if one of the numbers on the left side of this output is higher than 25.

**The output I current receive from my bash script:**

```
  3 00:05:00:E7:5A:EA
  3 00:0C:85:F2:F8:4E
  3 00:11:92:21:87:14
  3 00:17:C5:69:49:A1
  3 00:1A:E3:8C:E4:1A
  3 00:1D:A2:E7:BC:24
  3 00:26:98:14:91:05
  3 44:03:A7:C0:0D:26
 13 C0:62:6B:AE:6A:5D
 26 E8:B7:48:36:8C:AE
```

Above are the top 10 mac addresses with the most arp entries (Public IPs Only) from our cable plant.

**For example:** the bottom mac address is at 26 which should trigger and email alert that sends off to me with a subject of "Alert: Valid Info Here"

The extent of my bash scripting ability is basically groups of commands, so I'll need some real help with this one.

Comment: You don't have a real monitoring system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

msg=
count=0
while read line; do
    read freq mac <<< $line
    if (( $freq > 25 )) ; then 
        (( count ++ ))
        msg="$msg$line"$'\n'
    fi
done 
mail your@email.com -s "Alert: $count mac with more than 25 entries" <<< $msg
```

Redirect the output from your script into this script's standard input (typically with a pipe `|`) : your_script.sh | the_above_script.sh

Make sure to change the dummy email address. You will then receive an email with the line count in the subject and the full lines in the body.

Here is an example run where I inserted an `echo` just before the `mail` command

```
$ cat message
  3 00:05:00:E7:5A:EA
  3 00:0C:85:F2:F8:4E
  3 00:11:92:21:87:14
  3 00:17:C5:69:49:A1
  3 00:1A:E3:8C:E4:1A
  3 00:1D:A2:E7:BC:24
  3 00:26:98:14:91:05
  3 44:03:A7:C0:0D:26
 13 C0:62:6B:AE:6A:5D
 26 E8:B7:48:36:8C:AE
$ ./t.sh < message
mail your@email.com -s Alert: 1 mac with more than 25 entries <<< 26 E8:B7:48:36:8C:AE
```

If you can use `awk`, here is a shorter solution

```
< message.txt awk '{ if ($1>25) exit 1 }'  ||  mailx -s "Random Subject" myemail@mydomain.com < message.txt
```

Comment: Hmmm, I did a test by just adding that data to a txt file and piping it into this script. There was one device with more than 25 entries and it didn't report it. I was also wondering if it is possible to have it included at the end of my current script and have it just email the same output it normally does, but only if one of those mad addresses is over 25.

Comment: Is there any way we can simplify it a bit and just say if there is any number higher than 25 as the first word of any line "cat message.txt | mailx -s "Random Subject" myemail@mydomain.com". Message.txt being the file to check for > 25 and the output sent via email.

Comment: You can shorten it by using `awk`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: That worked perfectly using awk, thank you.